# JMeter logout POST request doesn't actually log out

Tags: http-headers, jmeter

I'm fairly new with JMeter and am trying to create a log in/log out script for my application with JMeter (2.13).  Log in works fine but the log out request isn't logging out.  If I look at the response body, it still has the page for the logged in user.

When I log out in Chrome, the request header has one cookie and the response header has set_cookie and a new cookie.  In JMeter both request and response header have the same cookie.

Am I missing a step somewhere?

Some notes: 
- I am using the an HTTP Cookie Manager
- The initial log out request redirects due to a 302 response.
- In both the log in and log out post requests I'm using the CSRF token that I extracted from the original GET request to go to the sign in page.
- I built the script with the recording tool (HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder)

Comment: Can you post your .jmx file?